# CakePHP 3 : parameter array key from url

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.x

I am passing multiple parameters in url like

```
http://website.com/controller/action/para1/para2/para3/para4/para5
```

Now I have to access `para4`

How could I access `para4` ?

> Edit 2 : output of `debug($this->request->params)`

```
[
    'plugin' => null,
    'controller' => 'ServiceRequests',
    'action' => 'checkout',
    '_ext' => null,
    'pass' => [
        (int) 0 => '7e441d08-fdb2-4f86-9a36-d15c61a8a4f0',
        (int) 1 => 'b95c0ca1-7782-4621-ad37-cccf697c777c',
        (int) 2 => '3df2d1c5-18c6-4c4b-a3bf-c763ce1b41c7',
        (int) 3 => 'ac1f0acd-b7d2-4d61-b37d-4990e4774392',
        (int) 4 => '1',
        (int) 5 => '338ae9f9-0973-4943-b6e1-c12a7713af89'
    ],
    'isAjax' => false
]
```

Comment: Depends on the route that you've defined to match that URL. You may want to add that to your question.

Comment: i haven't added route. I'm expecting solution like `$ar[3]` or any index value that can be used to access any part of parameters or URL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At your controller (or wherever this request is handled), do 
 `debug($this->request->data) or debug($this->request->query) or debug($this->request->params)`.

I don't exactly recall which one of those will give you the parameters you want. If none of these show you your request structure which will allow you to understand how to access your parameters do `debug($this->request)`

When you debug you can see how to access these parameters. They should be an array of arguments so you should be able to access them pretty easily. If instead they appear as one variable separated by '/' you can use php's explode function to add them all in an array, something like:

```
$data = explode('/', $this->request->data);
```

Comment: I have added output of `debug($this->request->params)` how to access `pass` array elements in view.

Comment: got it working by `$this->request->params['pass']['3]`